# How can I solve merge conflict however the changes in different lines of the same file (which conflict here suppose not happen)?

Tags: git

What causes the merge conflict and How can I solve merge conflict however the changes in different lines of the same file (which conflict here suppose not happen)?

**master-base**

```
Hello
Second line
Third line.
```

**branch-base**

```
Hello, my first conflict.
Second line
Third line.
```

**branch-a**

```
Hello
Second line.
Third line.a. # changed this line
```

And I executed the following code, it says git merge conflict.

```
$ git checkout branch-base
$ git merge branch-a

<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
Third line.a.
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

Comment: You show the contents of only two files. What is the third one (I guess you do not show the base version)?

Comment: If two changes *overlap* (e.g., person A changes "red ball" to "blue ball", and person B changes "red ball" to "red square") you get a conflict because Git doesn't know which change(s) to take. But if changes *abut* (touch at the edges), you *still* get a conflict, because the people who write merge algorithms find that this produces better results than if you didn't get a conflict. Either way you must resolve the conflict.

Comment: As @j6t mentioned, a merge conflict involves *three* files: a common (shared) base version, and two modified versions of that same common base version. If you set `diff.conflictStyle` to `diff3` (instead of `merge`), Git will show all three versions in the working tree copy. With `diff.conflictStyle` set to `merge` (or unset, so that it defaults to `merge`), Git shows you only two of the three versions in the working tree copy. In all cases the three inputs are still available, and `git mergetool` will give all three inputs to your chosen external (non-Git) merge tool.

Comment: Added the third file

Comment: This constellation should not lead to a conflict. And in fact, when I attempt the merge with the information given, I cannot reproduce the conflict. It is a clean automatic merge.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're already in conflicted state, you can execute:

```
git checkout --theirs .
git add .
```

`--theirs` in your case means you prefer version from remote repository.
If you prefer yours, you should replace `--theirs` with `--ours`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried both but I just do not need a blind copy by using --theirs
So I have used --ours 
But I got some changes from the remote branch got merged to my branch
And actually, I am curious  why all upstream changes lead to a merge conflict